# Using numpy matmul in row-wise manner with broadcasting

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication, array-broadcasting, numpy-einsum

I have an array of 3D points (n,3) that are to be rotated about the origin using a 3x3rotation matrix that is stored in the form of a nx3x3 array.

At the moment I'm simply doing this in a for loop with `matmul` but I'm figuring this is pointless as there must be a much faster broadcasting way of doing it.

### Current code

```
n = 10
points = np.random.random([10,3])
rotation_matrices = np.tile(np.random.random([3,3]), (n,1,1))

result = []

for point in range(len(points)):
    rotated_point = np.matmul(rotation_matrices[point], points[point])

    result.append(rotated_point)

result = np.asarray(result)
```

Note: in this example I've just tiled the same rotation matrix but in my real case every 3x3 rotation matrix is different.

### What I want to do

I'm guessing there must be some way of broadcasting this as the `for` loop becomes very slow when the point-cloud becomes very large. I'd like to do this:

```
np.matmul(rotation_matrices, points)
```

where each `row` in `points` is multiplied by it's corresponding rotation matrix. There is probably a way to do this with `np.einsum` but I couldn't figure out the signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see [the doc](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html), `np.einsum('ij,jk', a, b)` is the signature for `matmul`.

So you can try `np.einsum` with the signature:

```
np.einsum('kij,kj->ki', rotation_matrices, points)
```

**Test**:

```
einsum = np.einsum('kij,kj->ki', rotation_matrices, points)
manual = np.array([np.matmul(x,y) for x,y in zip (rotation_matrices, points)])
np.allclose(einsum, manual)
# True
```

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't give the same result `np.allclose(result, np.einsum('kij,kj->ki', rotation_matrices, points))` =  False

Comment: @jpmorr True on my side. Make sure you don't re-generate the `rotation_matrices` and `points` in the two runs.

Comment: `np.matmul(rotation_matrices, points[...,None])` also work.